# Как тестировать route из useRoute компонента на composition api?

Tags: юнит-тесты, vue3, vue-router, mocha

Тестирование компонентов с использование composition api vuejs3

**Не могу тестировать компонент**, который использует router или route из библиотеки vue-router в тесте vue-test-utils, mocka, chai. Мой компонент написан с использования синтаксиса composition api `<script setup>`

**При попытке запустить тест компонента, столкнулся с следующей проблемой**: route не существует внутри wrapper. Вот пример ошибки/неправильного поведения: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')`.

**Я уже попробовал** заглушать route вот так:

```
  let wrapper
  const route = { path: '/hello' }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, {
      props: {
        msg: 'Hello!'
      },
      global: {
        mocks: {
          route
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

Это сработало для такого компонента `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

defineProps({
  msg: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const route = useRoute();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="greetings">
    <h1 class="green">{{ route.path }}</h1>
    <h1 class="green">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Но не сработало для такого, почему?

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

defineProps({
  msg: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const route = useRoute();

const path = computed(() => {
  return route.path;
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="greetings">
    <h1 class="green">{{ path }}</h1>
    <h1 class="green">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Я ожидал**, что тесты будут проходить в обоих случая, но вместо этого для второго теста получаю `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')`.

Буду благодарен за любые советы или рекомендации по решению проблемы тестирования compositon api компоненты. Спасибо!